# How to modify table and create bins for histogram representation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am a bit new to **R** and I was experimenting with ggplot.

I have a table like this:

[table http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43697/temporary/data_frame.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43697/temporary/data_frame.jpg)

I would like to modify the table to set bins based on different breaks and record the frequency for each bin:

[table http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43697/temporary/data_frame2.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43697/temporary/data_frame2.jpg)

I guess the first thing to do would be to set breaks on the year columns and later transpose them to match the AllotmentID.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your image links are broken. Please update them so your question stays well-formatted for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, and no hint of what sort of graph you'd like to make using `ggplot2`, all I can do is point you in the direction of a useful tool. In this case I suspect you will want to make good use of the function `cut`, which is usually the go-to tool in R for binning.

`cut` will return a factor, which you will likely want to pass to `table` to count the number of observations in each "bin".

**EDIT**

Here's a very bare bones example. You will want to tinker with it to make the breaks and bins work out the way you want them to:

```
set.seed(123)
X <- runif(100,30,60)
table(cut(X,breaks=seq(30,60,by=5),labels=paste(as.character(seq(30,55,by=5)),"%",sep="")))
```

Comment: I actually don't need to do any plotting inside of R.  I just want to use R to transform the data.  Do you know of any specific examples that I might be able to follow?

Comment: I added some more detail that hopefully helps. You can also consult `?cut` and `?table` for more help.